# Why do I get the error "-4046" when running my nodemailer backend program

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, node-modules, nodemailer

When I followed the steps from the nodemailer website I keep on getting this error message.

```
Error: write EPROTO C44A0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
  errno: -4046,
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write',
  type: 'FETCH',
  sourceUrl: 'https://api.nodemailer.com/user'
```

This is my code in the block below

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"


async function notify() {
    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
 
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: 'email@outlook.com', 
        pass: 'password', 
      },
    });
  
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'email@outlook.com', // sender address
      to: "recipient@outlook.com", // list of receivers
      subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
      text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    });
  
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...

  }
notify().catch(console.error);
```

I have tried changing my port number but nothing seems to work.